# Test statistics for randomization

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clinical-trials, random-allocation

I have a basic question on what method should be applied to obtain test statistics distribution.

I have two treatments $A$ and $B$. I want to test on mean $H_0: \overline{t}_A=\overline{t}_B$ as hypothesis where $t_i$ is treatment effect of $i=A$ or $B$ with $t_i$ continuous variable. I have recruited 100 patients. I decided to apply permuted block randomization with 25 blocks.

Should I naively use $t$ statistics to test $H_0$ here?(One may need to check whether the variances within each treatment are the same here.) Under this $H_0$, I cannot construct unobserved outcome as in sharp null hypothesis and this restricts me to consider $t-$test. It seems that randomization is never invoked during this $t$ statistics calculation other than possibly balancing covariates. Am I wrong here? And if I do not do block randomization, I could just do simple randomization instead. It would not make significant difference other than unbalancing issue.

Comment: I didn't understand your question well, but in summary you proceeded with the application of two treatments (A and B) in 100 patients. For example, 50 received treatment A and 50 received treatment B and later I would like to compare the averages of the treatments, is that it?

Comment: Remember that an important assumption of permutation tests, if you want application, is that the observations are interchangeable. In the case of a t test of difference of means this would imply equal variances.

Comment: @jassis Sorry for late reply. For the treatment assignment, permuted block randomization is not the same as random allocation. There is chance that 40 people have A and 60 people have B and the chance of previous situation is reduced in permuted block randomization approach. I agree that assumption of equal variance for all participants outcome is required here due to symmetry. It seems that average test statistics knows nothing about the randomization procedure whereas sharp null does.